# Benefits of a swap function?

Tags: c++, stl, swap

Browsing through some C++ questions I have often seen comments that a STL-friendly class should implement a `swap` function (usually as a friend.)  Can someone explain what benefits this brings, how the STL fits into this and why this function should be implemented as a `friend`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For most classes, the default swap is fine, however, the default swap is not optimal in all cases. The most common example of this would be a class using the [Pointer to Implementation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29) idiom. Where as with the default swap a large amount of memory would get copied, is you specialized swap, you could speed it up significantly by only swapping the pointers.

If possible, it shouldn't be a friend of the class, however it may need to access private data (for example, the raw pointers) which you class probably doesn't want to expose in the class API.

Answer (score 24):

The standard version of std::swap() will work for most types that are assignable.

```
void std::swap(T& lhs,T& rhs)
{
    T tmp(lhs);
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = tmp;
}
```

But it is not an optimal implementation as it makes a call to the copy constructor followed by two calls to the assignment operator.

By adding your own version of std::swap() for your class you can implement an optimized version of swap().

For example std::vector. The default implementation as defined above would be very expensive as you would need to make copy of the whole data area. Potentially release old data areas or re-allocate the data area as well as invoke the copy constructor for the contained type on each item copied. A specialized version has a very simple easy way to do std::swap()

```
// NOTE this is not real code.
// It is just an example to show how much more effecient swaping a vector could
// be. And how using a temporary for the vector object is not required.
std::swap(std::vector<T>& lhs,std::vector<T>& rhs)
{
    std::swap(lhs.data,rhs.data);  // swap a pointer to the data area
    std::swap(lhs.size,rhs.size);  // swap a couple of integers with size info.
    std::swap(lhs.resv,rhs.resv);
}
```

As a result if your class can optimize the swap() operation then you should probably do so. Otherwise the default version will be used.

Personally I like to implement swap() as a non throwing member method. Then provide a specialized version of std::swap():

```
class X
{
    public:
        // As a side Note:
        //    This is also useful for any non trivial class
        //    Allows the implementation of the assignment operator
        //    using the copy swap idiom.
        void swap(X& rhs) throw (); // No throw exception guarantee
};


  // Should be in the same namespace as X.
  // This will allows ADL to find the correct swap when used by objects/functions in
  // other namespaces.
  void swap(X& lhs,X& rhs)
  {
     lhs.swap(rhs);
  }
```

Comment: As of C++11, the "standard version of `std::swap()`" has changed to use `std::move()` for move-constructable classes, I think this answer should be edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to swap (for example) two vectors without knowing anything about their implementation, you basically have to do something like this:

```
typedef std::vector<int> vec;

void myswap(vec &a, vec &b) {
   vec tmp = a;
   a = b;
   b = tmp;
}
```

This is not efficient if `a` and `b` contain many elements since all those elements are copied between `a`, `b` and `tmp`.

But if the swap function would know about and have access to the internals of the vector, there might be a more efficient implementation possible:

```
void std::swap(vec &a, vec &b) {
   // assuming the elements of the vector are actually stored in some memory area
   // pointed to by vec::data
   void *tmp = a.data;
   a.data = b.data;
   b.data = tmp;
   // ...
}
```

In this implementation just a few pointers need to be copied, not all the elements like in the first version. And since this implementation needs access to the internals of the vector it has to be a friend function.

Answer (score 12):

I interpreted your question as basically three different (related) questions.

1. Why does STL need swap?
2. Why should a specialized swap be implemented (i.s.o. relying on the default `swap`)?
3. Why should it be implemented as a friend?

> Why does STL need swap?

The reason an STL friendly class needs `swap` is that `swap` is used as a primitive operation in many STL algorithms. (e.g. `reverse`, `sort`, `partition` etc. are typically implemented using `swap`)

> Why should a specialized swap be implemented (i.s.o. relying on the default `swap`)?

There are many (good) answers to this part of your question already. Basically, knowing the internals of a class frequently allows you to write a much more optimized `swap` function.

> Why should it be implemented as a friend?

The STL algorithms will always call swap as a free function. So it needs to be available as a non member function to be useful. 
 And, since it's only beneficial to write a customized swap when you can use knowledge of internal structures to write a much more efficient swap, this means your free function will need access to the internals of your class, hence a friend.

Basically, it doesn't *have* to be a friend, but if it doesn't need to be a friend, there's usually no reason to implement a custom swap either.

Note that you should make sure the free function is inside the same namespace as your class, so that the STL algorithms can find your free function via Koening lookup.

Comment: STL is not required to use `swap()` in any algorithm.  Many of the algorithms tend to use `std::iter_swap()` which may or may not use `std::swap()`.

Answer (score 10):

One other use of the swap function is to aid exception-safe code: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/059.htm

Comment: +1 - this is probably the most important reason to provide `swap` and, more importantly, a *non-throwing swap*!

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency:

If you've got a class that holds (smart) pointers to data then it's likely to be faster to swap the pointers than to swap the actual data - 3 pointer copies vs. 3 deep copies.

If you use a 'using std::swap' + an unqualified call to swap (or just a qualified call to boost::swap), then ADL will pick up the custom swap function, allowing efficient template code to be written.

---

Safety:

Pointer swaps (raw pointers, std::auto_ptr and std::tr1::shared_ptr) do not throw, so can be used to implement a non-throwing swap. A non-throwing swap makes it easier to write code that provides the strong exception guarantee (transactional code).

The general pattern is:

```
class MyClass 
{
  //other members etc...

  void method()
  {
    MyClass finalState(*this);//copy the current class
    finalState.f1();//a series of funcion calls that can modify the internal
    finalState.f2();//state of finalState and/or throw.
    finalState.f3();

    //this only gets call if no exception is thrown - so either the entire function 
    //completes, or no change is made to the object's state at all.
    swap(*this,finalState);
  }
};
```

As for whether it should be implemented as friend; swapping usually requires knowledge of implementation details. It's a matter of taste whether to use a non-friend that calls a member function or to use a friend.

---

Problems:

A custom swap is often faster than a single assignment - but a single assignment is always faster than the default three assignment swap. If you want to move an object, it's impossible to know in a generic way whether a swap or assignment would be best - a problem which C++0x solves with move constructors.

Comment: "it's impossible to know in a generic way whether a swap or assignment would be best" please see my answer, the compiler can often help you in this direction by optimizing away useless copies.

Answer (score 2):

To implement assignment operators:

```
class C
{
    C(C const&);
    void swap(C&) throw();
    C& operator=(C x) { this->swap(x); return *this; }
};
```

This is exception safe, the copy is done via the copy constructor when you pass by value, and the copy can be optimized out by the compiler when you pass a temporary (via [copy elision](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)).